# Best way to set up my DIY studio/recording/interfaces?

Tags: recording, mixer, studio, interface

I have a mixer that someone gave me, which has a built in USB interface, which introduces a horrible hiss into my computer when recording.

I purchased a Focusrite 6i6 interface, which provides recording capabilities without the horrible hiss that the mixer introduces.

However, I have 3 amps which are miked, along with 2 DI's from FX units, and 2 emulated speaker outputs. All these I had going into my mixer.

Now, I also have my computer which I want to use a set of speakers/subwoofer for playback and listening to music/other stuff on my pc. I also have a pair of powered monitors that I am not sure how or where to hook up.

Here is an inventory of my supplies:

- 18channel Mixer
- Focusrite 6i6 Interface
- Laptop
- Tube-based Poweramp (drives non-powered speakers and subwoofer) [used for the higher quality audiophile type stuff, even though I am not what I would consider an audiophile - yet]
- Subwoofer
- Yamaha NS-10 non-powered speakers
- Presonus powered monitors
- 3 amps which are miked
- 2 fx units which use direct-out
- 2 emulated speaker outputs, one from pedalboard, and one from one of the amps

**What I want to accomplish**

I would 'ideally' like to be able to play music/games/movies through the Yamaha speakers, which also goes to the subwoofer. I would like to also be able to record things through the mixer, and route that through the Focusrite into the computer. I also have the scenario where I would like to be able to playback a pre-recorded track on my PC to add other 'live' tracks to. If I can enable or disable that backing track from being added to the main recorded sample, that would be great too.

The trouble is, I do not know where to send the signal from my PC to, be it the 1/8" lineout from PC to mixer or focusrite, or directly via USB to the Focusrite and out to the mixer! The mixer has tons of knobs and buttons, and I only know what a handful of them do. I have tried reading the manuals associated but it usually doesn't end well in practice.

The Mixer has Main Mix sliders, control room outs, main outs, monitor sends, fx returns, and the likes. It also has RCA in/out too.

I am a total newbie when it comes to pro-sound like this, and I know I am probably asking a lot with this. I just do not know where to start.

Comment: What is the Brand/type of the mixer ?

Comment: It is a... Behringer Xenyx QX1832USB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was first going to write a long answer with all permutations on how you could hook everything up, in multiple configurations. However, this would be a very long answer, and would probably complex the matter in regards to the choices you need to make.

The positive thing is that you have a good audio interface, which will do most of what you want. The Focusrite 6i6 is a good interface with multiple in's and out's.

Let me address some of your questions in your post:

> I am a total newbie when it comes to pro-sound like this, and I know I
>   am probably asking a lot with this.

You have to start somewhere, and I would advice you to search on the internet in regards to "home recording". There are plenty of blogs and video's out there which are educational for a beginner.

Example:

There are plenty more, watch as much as possible, and try out yourself with your Focusrite interface.

Also read the Focusrite manual, all good information in there.

> I would 'ideally' like to be able to play music/games/movies through
>   the Yamaha speakers, which also goes to the subwoofer.

Your focusrite has 4 line outputs, you can use 2 of those (one L, and one R) to connect your amp/speakers. The configuration in your computer is dependend on the application, but start with the sound control panel for playback devices and choose the correct outputs.

> I would like to also be able to record things through the mixer, and
>   route that through the Focusrite into the computer.

hmmm, you start your post claiming that the mixer has a "hiss". Why not use the Focusrite directly. A link above shows a video instructable with a Focusrite.

> I also have the scenario where I would like to be able to playback a
>   pre-recorded track on my PC to add other 'live' tracks to.

Yep, you can do that, another video:

(I have no affiliation with this YouTube channel/user, but there is good infomration out there, all over YouTube, not only this channel/user)

> If I can enable or disable that backing track from being added to the
>   main recorded sample, that would be great too

This would depend all on the DAW (recording software) you are using. Once you get started and have specific questions, it would be a great follow up question.

> The trouble is, I do not know where to send the signal from my PC to,
>   be it the 1/8" lineout from PC to mixer or focusrite, or directly via
>   USB to the Focusrite and out to the mixer

You connect the Focusrite using USB to the PC/Laptop

> The mixer has tons of knobs and buttons, and I only know what a
>   handful of them do. I have tried reading the manuals associated but it
>   usually doesn't end well in practice.

Although the above answers are all omitting the mixer, in order to start learning about your mixer, you may search for information. Use search terms like "gain structure in mixer", "signal flow in mixer".

> I have a mixer that someone gave me, which has a built in USB
>   interface, which introduces a horrible hiss into my computer when
>   recording

You will need to troubleshoot this, which would be a good follow up question. There are many area's which can cause this, examples:

- Ground Loops
- Faulty cabling
- Mixer fault
- Power supply interference
- and many more...

> I just do not know where to start

Read as much as you can on the subject, watch video's, go to conferences, buy some books... and do it, experiment, talk to others (in real life or on blogs)... and when you have specific questions come back here and ask questions (this is not a blog but a Q&A site)

Good Luck.